# Converting a formatted string into date time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string of this format :

```
a~b~c~[character][year]

eg:
x = a~b~c~f16 represent january 2016.
```

Below os the character and month mapping:

```
month_dict = {'F': 1,
              'G': 2,
              'H': 3,
              'J': 4,
              'K': 5,
              'M': 6,
              'N': 7,
              'Q': 8,
              'U': 9,
              'V': 10,
              'X': 11,
              'Z': 12
              }
```

I want to find out the last business date of this month in yyyymmdd format. Can someone help me in this?

I am trying to do the following:

```
m = x.split(~)
def last_business_day_in_month(year: int, month: int) -> int:
    return max(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)[-1:][0][:5])



x = last_business_day_in_month(m[3][1:], month_dict[3][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#module-re), [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) and [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/calendar.html#module-calendar)

```py
import re
import datetime
import calendar

month_dict = {'F': 1,
              'G': 2,
              'H': 3,
              'J': 4,
              'K': 5,
              'M': 6,
              'N': 7,
              'Q': 8,
              'U': 9,
              'V': 10,
              'X': 11,
              'Z': 12
}

x = f"a~b~c~f16"

result = re.search("[f-z]\d+", x).group(0)
letter = result[0]
year = int(result[1:])
month = month_dict[letter.upper()]

last_business_day = max(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)[-1:][0][:5])

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(f"{last_business_day} {month} {year}", "%d %m %y")
formatted_date = date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
print(formatted_date)
```

Output

```
20160129
```

Comment: This wull not give the last business date in the datetime format as 2016-01-29

Comment: Maybe you already copied the code before I updated it. I made a mistake. Should work now

Comment: It still outputs 2016-01-01
29.

The desired output for this would be 01/29/2016

Comment: There are two print statements. The first one is just to demonstrate that it's a datetime object. The second print is the last business day. In this case `29`

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL Just realised that you want it in `yyyymmdd` format. Sorry for that, I updated it

Comment: It would not work if the year happens to be less than 10